# Nested form for has_many through association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, reservations and tables, with has_many through relationship between them with a join table and model collections, that has a separate attribute called :units_sold

my Reservation model:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tables, through: :collections
  has_many :collections
end
```

my table model:

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :reservations, through: :collections
  has_many :collections
end
```

and finally the collection model:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :table
  belongs_to :reservation
end
```

E.g:

A reservation in my name for 9 people (:units_sold) has 2 tables each with a capacity of 6 and I want 4 people in one table and 5 on the second table

What I have currently is this:

reservation_params

```
def reservation_params
  params.require(:reservation).permit( :name, :total_units, table_ids: [],
                                collection_attributes: [ :units_sold],
                                table_attributes: [:capacity, :title])
end
```

and my form to submit a reservation:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @account, @reservation] do |f| %>

<header>
    <h1>Make your reservation</h1>
</header>

    <%= f.text_field :name,         placeholder: "Name" %>
    <%= f.number_field :total_units,     placeholder: "How many people..." %>
    <%= f.fields_for :collections  do |c|%>
        <% @tables.each do |p| %>

            <label for="<%= p.title %>"><%= p.title %></label>
            <%= c.number_field :units_sold,     placeholder: "People per table..." %>
            <%= check_box_tag "reservation[table_ids][]", p.id %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>     

<% end %>
```

How should I do the reservation_params in the reservation controller? And nest the form to accept :units_sold for each table/reservation association

Answer (score 0):

First, you should define the associations like :

has_many :collections

has_many :reservations, through: :collections

as in, first define collections and then reservations through collections. Similarly, update the associations in the Table model.

Then in the reservation model after defining the associations, add the following line:

accepts_nested_attributes_for :collections

In reservation_params, the key "collection_attributes" and "table_attributes" should be "collections_attributes" and "tables_attributes" respectively.

Comment: I did that but, when I put in the reservation model, accepts_nested_attributes_for :collections it makes disappear the form fields below the f.number_field :total_units

Comment: update the line <%= f.fields_for :collections  do |c|%> to :
<%= f.fields_for :collections, f.object.collections || f.object.collections.build  do |c|%>

This will return existing collections for reservation, and if there are not any, it will initialize a collection object

Comment: and I'm still getting an error on the terminal saying "Unpermitted parameters: collections"

Comment: Have you added accepts_nested_attributes_for :collections in the Reservation model?